# Assign constructor parameter to object variable - Delphi

Tags: delphi

I keep getting error dialog:

> Access violation at address XXXX in module 'XXXX.exe'. Write of
>   address XXXX.

What should I do?

```
constructor TCustomClass.Create(ID: Integer);
begin
  self.ID := ID;
end;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Along with Craig's likely correct answer below, you need to call the inherited constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The odds are the problem is that you're calling the constructor incorrectly. You're probably doing something similar to the following:

```
var
  LInstance: TCustomClass;
begin
  LInstance.Create(1);
  ...
end;
```

The problem is that `LInstance` doesn't exist yet, but you're calling a method on it. You need to create the instance as follows: `LInstance := TCustomClass.Create(1);`

Comment: My first guesss too.